# Trigger selection for the requirement

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, triggers

I am going to implement a TRIGGER in a table, and how I look at it is :

When ever any row added/updated/deleted from the database, the trigger would fire and insert the primary key of the table to another table.

I read about trigger and it seems there are few cases when this does not trigger.

Please suggest whether trigger suits my need here, and if yes which type of trigger I should be using??

Comment: In general I would recommend you try to avoid using triggers that INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE data. Use triggers to enforce business rules that cannot otherwise be implemented as constraints. Use stored procedures to populate tables. Use CDC or change tracking to keep audit history.

Comment: I want to track which records are insert/update/ delete from a table...and apply a stored procedure on them through a job schedule in SQL Server

Comment: There are lots of ways to do that without using a trigger. Just use a scheduled job to check the table periodically. Or put change events onto a Service Broker queue. Or use CDC.

Comment: CDC is something I was looking for..I am reading more on this..thanks

Comment: @sqlvogel I am not sure about the performance gain or loss by suing CDC over trigger..All I need is..to get the PK of the rows added/updated from a database..and a scheduled job will process some logic on those item..then remove that item from that table..